# Set a curl output to a variable in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, command-line-interface, sh

basically i'm doing a curl and grepping some stuff.
But, i want set the output of this curl to a variable, to then use it on another curl.
e.g:

```
curl -u asd:asd http://zzz:123/aa/aa.aaa?cmd=ls | grep -B1 -E '<bbb>[4-7]\d{8,}' | grep yyy | tail -n 1 | sed -n -e 's/.*<xxx>\(.*\)<\/xxx>.*/\1/p')
```

but then I want set the output to a var and use it:

```
RUN aaa=$(previous curl) && curl -u asd:asd http://$aaa.com
```

tried with ${aaa}, with "$aaa", etc... didn't work. any solutions?

UPDATE:
something wrong is happening in previous curl 'cause doesn't return the value. probably for not doing the curl

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/1563297

Comment: "*... didn't work. ..."* - what does that mean? Is the variable empty? Has it an unexpected value?

Comment: @SergioSantiago I don’t think so, I need to run it inside my dockerfile

Comment: @Turing85 yes, empty. However in the cmd directly works

Comment: Are you trying to run these in the same `RUN` command, or in separate lines?  Assuming you fill in "previous curl" correctly, the last `RUN` line you show seems like it should be correct.

Comment: @DavidMaze same RUN command. seems like it doesn't run the curl, 'cause in the commandline works perfectly

Comment: bump bump bump pls help

Answer (score 0):

I fear you will not be able to acheive this, because from my understanding RUN statement is to execute a command. To store value you'll have use SET.

For me the following workaround helped

```
RUN export aaa=$(curl -u asd:asd http://$aaa.com);echo aaa;
```

You can add the downsteam commands that will use the variable `aaa` towards right of the semicolon